# How to loop through the columns in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, lag

I have a following vector `h=c("a","b","c","d","e")`

I would like to create the dataset that looks like that using `lag()` function:

```
pr <- data.frame(your_github         = h, 
                 review_this1        = lag(h),
                 review_this2        = lag(h,2))
```

However, when I use lag the following happens:
col2=c(NA,"a","b","c","d") and col3=(NA,NA,"a","b","c")

but I need to get outcome similar to `data.frame(col1=c("a","b","c","d","e"),col2=c("b","c","d","e","a"), col3=("c","d","e","a","b"))` where values in col2 and col3 are looped (i.e the 2nd column is just teh 1st one that is lagged by 1, but the 1st item in 2nd is teh last item in st column).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(dplyr) 

h = c("a","b","c","d","e")
pr <- data.frame(your_github = h,
                 review_this1 = ifelse(is.na(lead(h)), h[1], lead(h)),
                 review_this2 = ifelse(is.na(lead(h, 2)), h[2:1], lead(h, 2)))
pr

#  your_github review_this1 review_this2
#1           a            b            c
#2           b            c            d
#3           c            d            e
#4           d            e            a
#5           e            a            b
```

Comment: I only changed ```review_this2 = ifelse(is.na(lead(h, 2)), h[2:1], lead(h, 2)))``` i replaced ```h[2:1]``` to ```h[1:2]``` to avoid having rows with same letters in 2nd and 3rd columns

Answer (score 2):

With base R you can achieve this with `head` and `tail` (test on [tio here](https://tio.run/##fY7BCsIwEETv@Yo9ZiEREvAi9UtESrRrNxBr2W4Vvz7agwoivtMMzIORWrnxhVRJpl3YrPemLH3olS2jGQUaD13StDpJOpO9X2Zp@6w8H@DFFtiBgW@ErplurXKewmd6tJpysex8QMeUumcMiO6vH3/58e1HxOVqHtSOgqbWBw)):

```
h<-letters[1:5]
pr <- data.frame(your_github         = h, 
                 review_this1        = c(tail(h, -1), head(h, -1)),
                 review_this2        = c(tail(h, -2), head(h, -2)))
print(pr)
```

Output:

```
  your_github review_this1 review_this2
1           a            b            c
2           b            c            d
3           c            d            e
4           d            e            a
5           e            a            b
```

The idea is to take the start of the vector `h` with tail and concatenate it with the end  of the vector taken by `head` minus what we got from tail so we have the same length at end for each column (vector) of the dataframe.

If you want to cycle the vector with last value becoming the first, just reverse the signs in tail and head.

Comment: This doesn't match the expected output - don't you want `c(tail(h, -1), head(h, 1))` and `c(tail(h, -2), head(h, 2))`?